# printing one element of a dataframe in a magrittr pipe

Tags: r, dplyr, magrittr

Consider this simple example

```
library(dplyr)
library(glue)
library(magrittr)

> mydata <- data_frame(value = c(1,2,3))
> mydata
# A tibble: 3 x 1
  value
  <dbl>
1    1.
2    2.
3    3.
```

I would like to print the second element of my column `value2` in my dataframe from within a `magrittr` pipe.

I know I can exploit the `tee` operator in `magrittr`, but as you can see below my code does not work:

1. it does not print anything
2. it does not extract the value itself. Indeed`"the second element of value2 is 1"` is merely a string. I also tried some variants with `glue::"the second element of {} is {}"` without success.

For instance,

```
> mydata %>% mutate(value2 = value - 1) %T>% 
    print('the second element of value2 is 1') %>% 
    summarize(count = n())
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  value value2
  <dbl>  <dbl>
1    1.     0.
2    2.     1.
3    3.     2.
# A tibble: 1 x 1
  count
  <int>
1     3
```

Any ideas how to do that programmatically?
Thanks!

Comment: thanks, made some changes. I think you see better now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With sprintf:

```
nm = "value2"
mydata %>% mutate(value2 = value - 1) %T>% {
  cat(sprintf('the second element of %s is %s.\n', nm, nth(.[[nm]], 2))) } %>% 
  summarize(count = n())

the second element of value2 is 1.
# A tibble: 1 x 1
  count
  <int>
1     3
```

Or with glue

```
nm = "value2"
mydata %>% mutate(value2 = value - 1) %T>% {
  x = nth(.[[nm]], 2)
  cat(glue('the second element of {nm} is {x}.\n\n')) } %>% 
  summarize(count = n())

the second element of value2 is 1.
# A tibble: 1 x 1
  count
  <int>
1     3
```

For some reason, `glue` eats the first newline (`\n`).

The `{}` are needed since `"egad" %T>% print("some words")` evaluates to `print("egad", "some words")` according to magrittr semantics.

Comment: thanks, very interesting. any reason we should have a `cat` here? why only using `print` does not work?

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ `cat` will print more nicely (without the leading `[1]` and quotation marks, recognizing whitespace characters, etc). Try eg `x = "words\tafter a tab\nand after a newline\n"; print(x); cat(x)`

Comment: thanks Frank. amazing solution. Just a last point: are the double brackets necessarily needed here?  `nth(.[[nm]]`

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ Yes, I think so. If you do `data[nm]` it returns a data.frame and nth would be the nth row of that, not the same as the nth value of the column. If you do `data$nm` it won't work either since the text after `$` isn't "evaluated". I guess there is a "tidy" alternative to using it, though. In magrittr, there's extract2, that I think works.